# Why my actions on Google doesn't recognize touch selection?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm writing a simple action on google without any webhooks. Every response is generated by dialogflow.

I have an intent that works flawless if I call it by speech or type but if I call it by selecting it from a list it doesn't work and the Default Fallback is called.

In the simulator it show the right "text" when I click on the list.

Have I done something wrong or did I need to specify something in the list?

This is how the list is generated
[image]

This is my intent
[image]

This is what happens in the simulator if I click on the "easyTravel" item in the list (it trigger the default fallback intent)

[image]

This is what happens in the simulator if I type "easyTravel" (the right intent is executed)

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots to your question to illustrate how you're sending the list to the user and the Intent you think should be handing the response?

Comment: @Prisoner screenshots added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch a click on a list I need an intent configured to be triggered by the event **actions_intent_OPTION**

Answer (score 1):

Only once I read this question - and your anwser - I could fix my own problem. Just to share: if you are using a webhook and are waiting for a webhook actions in your script, you can create a new intent, which has the event as @Edo states: actions_intent_OPTION. If you define an action in that intent, this is what will be trigger by your webhook. You can then get the parameter by (node.js):

```
const param = app.getSelectedOption();
```

Without the 'empty' intent, with the event and action, I was not receiving any input.